# Applying styles to a GridView matching certain criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm fairly new to ASP.Net so it's probably just me being a bit stupid, but I just can't figure out why this isn't working.

Basically, I have a GridView control (GridView1) on a page which is reading from a database. I already have a CSS style applied to the GridView and all I want to do is change the background image applied in the style depending on if a certain cell has data in it or not.

The way I'm trying to handle this change is updating the CSS class applied to each row through C#. I have the code below doing this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = e.Row;
    string s = row.Cells[7].Text;

    if (s.Length > 0)
    {
        row.CssClass = "newRowBackground";
    }
    else
    {
        row.CssClass = "oldRowBackground";
    }
}
```

In theory, the data from Cell[7] will either be null or be a string (in this case, likely a person's name).

The problem is that when the page loads, every row in the GridView has the new style applied to it, whether it's empty or not. However, when I change it to use hard coded examples, it works fine. So for example, the below would work exactly how I want it to:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = e.Row;
    string s = row.Cells[7].Text;

    if (s == "Smith") //Matching a name in one of the rows
    {
        row.CssClass = "newRowBackground";
    }
    else
    {
        row.CssClass = "oldRowBackground";
    }
}
```

It seems as if the top piece of code is always returning the string with a value greater than 0, but when I check the database the fields are all null (except for my test record of "Smith").

I'm probably doing something very simple that's wrong here, but I can't see what. Like I said, I'm still very new to this. One thing I have tried is changing the argument in the if statement to things like: `if (s != null)`, `if (s != "")` and `if (s == string.empty)` all with no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated and don't hesitate to tell me if I'm just being stupid here. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the code below.

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.trim()))
{

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. It didn't solve my problem but it did inspire me to check out the HTML of the outputted GridView. Turns out that for empty fields the GridView places an &nbsp; into the HTML. By changing the if statement to read: 'if ( s != "&nbsp;")' it works exactly how I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that you only set the CssClass on DataRows.

Check for

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{

}
```

You might also take a look at scartags answer.

If nothing of the above metioned works, set a breakpoint into  the row where you match s against the string and have a look at the actual value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if((e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.trim()))
{
     return;
}
row.CssClass = "newRowBackground";
```

This assumes that the oldRowBackground CSS class would be applied by default.